# Как заменить содержимое строки в txt в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, файлы

Как заменить строку в файле `*.txt`?

Например:

*hi.txt:*

```html
Hi
Hallo
Hello
```

Я хочу написать вместо `Hallo` `guten Tag`, при этом удаляя `Hallo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Откройте файл в режиме чтения и записи (`r+`)
2. Прочитайте его содержимое (`read`), заменить нужный текст (`replace`)
3. Перейдите в начало файла (`seek`)
4. Урежьте файл (`truncate`)
5. Запишите текст (`write`)

***Пример:***

```
def main():
    with open('hi.txt', 'r+') as f:                    # 1
        text = f.read().replace('Hallo', 'guten Tag')  # 2

        f.seek(0)                                      # 3
        f.truncate()                                   # 4
        f.write(text)                                  # 5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*hi.txt:*

```html
Hi
guten Tag
Hello
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь

Comment: @Sanya_nedoprogramist Если ответ помог Вам, то Вы можете отметить его как верный, нажав на галочку слева от него. Это будет лучшая благодарность :)

Comment: Простите за дополнительное беспокойство, у меня при исполнение кода исчезает Hi (т.е. первая строчка)

Comment: @Sanya_nedoprogramist Это довольно странно, у меня такого не происходит. Я тестировал код на `Windows`, используя `Python 3.8`. Попробуйте создать новый файл и протестировать программу на нём (скопировав код из вопроса), может быть, Вы просто где-то опечатались.

Comment: А я тестировал на Python 3.7 на Mac os, и я уже пробовал создавать новый файл